# OWLAPI 4: import or merge ontologies?

Tags: owl, owl-api

I have a situation like follows:
I have three core ontologies which have their TBox and ABox descriptions respectively. They need to be imported/merged at runtime. I also need to import/merge other ontologies one at a time which hold only ABox descriptions. The last ones must be loaded and removed dynamically with time passing. 
My dilemma is whether to use import or merge of OWLAPI 4?

UPDATE:
The core ontologies ABox will eventually be modified based on incoming data from dynamical load of "part-time" ontologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import sounds like the best strategy, since you didn't mention modifications to any of the ontologies, but only additions and removals of whole ontologies.

I would do the following:

- create a new, empty ontology
- import all the ontologies that will always be included
- add/remove imports to the ontologies that you only want to use for part of the time

Note: OWLAPI does not load ontologies at the point in which the imports declaration is created - this is to avoid long loading times when one is just editing the imports. So for this to work you'll have to load the ontologies you plan to use beforehand:

- Load ontology X
- add import declaration to Y: `Y imports X`

Most query methods on OWLOntology accept a parameter to tell whether you wish the search to include the imports closure - you're likely to want to set this to Imports. INCLUDED all the time.

Comment: Yes correct I didn't mention the modifications. The core ontologies ABox will be modified based on incoming data from "part-time" ontologies. The question was modified to include this information

Comment: This complicates the design a bit, but you should still be able to use the answer above. You can modify imported ontologies, you just lose the convenience of modifying only the root ontology.

Comment: If I create a new empty ontology and other ones import into it I will not be able to do modifications on the root i.e. empty ontology but I will be able to do on other ones. Am I right?

Comment: Not exactly. If ontology a imports b, and you add or remove an axiom to a, the change will always be applied to a, never to b. So, an imported ontology cannot be modified through the importing ontology. However, nothing stops you from applying your changes to b directly; the only difficulty is to ensure the right change is applied to the right ontology.

Comment: What about ontology merging? Isn't it more suitable on my scenario?

Comment: For the core ontologies, it might be ok. I would not recommend it for the ontologies that you plan to add and remove - it's doable but it will be computationally more expensive. Also, consider duplicate axioms: if an axiom appears in both a core ontology and a temporary ontology, when you merge core and temporary you will only keep one copy of the axiom. When you then remove all the axioms contained in the temporary ontology, the single copy of the duplicate axiom will be removed as well. This problem won't exist for imports.